# How to link @BeforeEach method with specific @Test methods (Java, JUnit)?

Tags: java, junit, web-api-testing

For example we have 2 classes: BaseTest and Test. Test extends BaseTest.

`BaseTest.class` contains 2 methods with `@BeforeEach` annotations.

```
@BeforeEach
  void setUp1() {}

@BeforeEach
  void setUp2() {}
```

`Test.class` contains 2 methods with `@Test` annotations.

```
@Test
  void test1() {}

@Test
  void test2() {}
```

Is there a way to link the `@BeforeEach` method with `@Test` method, so the `setup1()` would run only before `test1()` and the `setup2()` would run only before `test2()`?

Answer (score 4):

You can't really do this, but you can bundle Testcases with with `@Nested` classes.

```
public class Test {


    @BeforeEach
    void setUpForAll() {}

    @Nested
    class TestCasesWithPrecondition1{

        @BeforeEach
        void setUp1() {}
        
        @Test
        void test1() {}
    }

    @Nested
    class TestCasesWithPrecondition2{

        @BeforeEach
        void setUp2() {}

        @Test
        void test2() {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A distinct non-answer: don't do that!

The purpose of your unit tests is to help you to identify breakages in your production code **quickly**. Thus a base rule is: keep a very simple structure.

One aspect of a *good* unit test is: you look at the test method, and you know what is going on. If at all, you have to scroll to some `setUp()` method above (same file!) to see what is going on.

What you intend to do requires that future readers not only have to know about that base class, they also have to understand that there is some complex logic in play that uses different mechanisms *per* test method.

So, yes, avoiding code duplication is important for unit tests, too. But you avoid "getting there" by applying the same patterns that you use for your production code.

Comment: Additionally, I'd say don't get sucked into the idea that the classes in your production code need to map 1:1 to classes in your test code. It seems like your problem would probably be resolved by having two separate test classes, each with their own `@BeforeEach` relevant only to the tests in that class.

Comment: I'm qa and want to use this technique for backend api tests, not the unit ones.

Comment: I think the same probably still applies, albeit without the comment about 1:1 mapping. More, smaller classes is always better than fewer more complicated ones.